# Oracle VirtualBox full

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I'm using virtualbox under windows10.
Installation went OK, and Ubuntu 16.04 was installed OK.
As suggested, a 10 GB dynamic alloc drive was created.
But during system updates- a message poped that only 188MB is left on drive.

a) checked again- 10 GB is allocated.
b) only 5.7 GB is used ( as noted in System Monitor ), but indicates a 96% is already in use.

any ideas why ??
EDIT1: `df` added. 
partition changed to 30 GB ,but it was created as a diffrent partition and did not extend the VB partition as expected

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          1993120       0   1993120   0% /dev
tmpfs                          404000    6184    397816   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   5545568 4955376    285452  95% /
tmpfs                         2019992    8184   2011808   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         2019992       0   2019992   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      482922  127066    330922  28% /boot
tmpfs                          404000      52    403948   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: What is the usage of the hosting disk in windows10?

Comment: there is a free 50 GB

Comment: Can you run `df` in a terminal window and edit your question to include its output?

Comment: And how much RAM have you assigned to the VM? Typically the default installation will create a swap partition at least as big as the assigned RAM.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - added `df` out put

Comment: @MichaelBay - RAM assigned to be 4GB ... mayme that is the reason 4+ 6 GB == 10 ?

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo parted -l` to your question, please?  The output of `lsblk` would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer found on this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/cDgUwWkvuIY

Explaining how to resize partition of a virtual box

As Michael wrote- swap file size filled up 4 GB from a 10 GB